# Extract data between two pattern occurrences in dataframe column R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using R to perform some data manipulation. I want to extract all rows between 2 occurrences of a pattern. I have attached the dataframe image.

I want to extract all rows starting from 'edu-hist-mark' to 'objectives-mark' using "mark" as a pattern. But I am not sure how to achieve that. Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

EDIT:
After some manipulation , here is the data frame :

> Data<- data.frame(class_name = c("edu-hist-mark","date","date","educational","qualif","date","date","educational","qualif","role","company","objectives-mark","additional-info-hobby-mark","nominal"),
> text_val=c("EDUCATION AND QUALIFICATIONS:",2000,2003,"ILLINOIS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY","Master of Science,Computer Science",1999,2000,"MAHARASHTRA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY","Bachelor of Science","Mechanical Engineering","Enterprise Solution Architect","Liaison Technologies","SUMMARY:,PUBLICATIONS:","Abhay Daftari"))

Comment: Please do not post screenshot. Please use `dput` to share your data.

Comment: iif your data are form a DB - rows will not be in the same order every time. Without code/better explanation it is hard to guess what you want to achieve

Comment: @xhudik: The only pattern i see here is that some rows have the word "mark" which I want to use to extract all rows between them. The data is not from DB . But I am working with a lot a dataframes and all have column names like 'edu-hist-mark' or some column name containing word 'mark'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code below, I find the indices of the instances where your first column contains the pattern, "mark", and then subset the dataset to find all rows between the first and the second instance of that pattern. If there are more than two instances of that pattern, you can change the index to reflect how the data should be subsetted. Hope this helps!

```
Data[c(c(as.list(which(grepl("mark", Data$class_name)))[[1]]:as.list(which(grepl("mark", Data$class_name)))[[2]])), ]
```

Comment: @sparkh20: This works!! Thanks a lot. I have question though: How can i modify the code if I want to select the all rows starting with "edu-hist-mark" to next occurrence of "hist" . I ask this  because i am working with a lot of dataframes and  "edu-hist-mark" might not always appear at the top of data frame.

Comment: @sparkh20: Apologies for the above question. It is quite apparent. What I wanted to ask is  How can i modify the code if I want to select the all rows starting with "edu-hist-mark" to the end of dataframe? Appreciate your help thanks!!

Comment: @Vishnu: Since "edu-hist-mark" is the first instance of the "mark" pattern in your data, you can use the following to iterate from that to the end of the data: `Data[c(c(as.list(which(grepl("mark", Data$class_name)))[[1]]:nrow(Data))), ]`. You can change this code to iterate from the second instance of the mark pattern (objectives-mark) to the end by simply changing code above to: `Data[c(c(as.list(which(grepl("mark", Data$class_name)))[[2]]:nrow(Data))), ]`. Glad to help!

Comment: @sparkho: I am new to stackoverflow as a user so I cant do a +1 on your answer but I can accept your answer . Thanks a lot!!.